# Add Httpd service by linking to source install apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, php5, centos6

As title says, i need to add a service httpd to get the php and apache2 talking to one another it seems (by line in httpd.conf: AddType application/x-httpd-php .php)

I uninstalled the default httpd that was in CentOS 6.2, then did source install for apache2.2.21 (latest), same source install for php5.3.9.

My guess is they are not talking to each other since service httpd is not being recognized at all atm.

How do I link my current apache2 to work as httpd service that does not exist?

Comment: I doubt the source automatically installed a `/etc/init.d/httpd` script for you, hence the lack of `service httpd command`

Comment: Please clarify, you are able to get apache (httpd) running or no? I assume it is running because you say httpd and php are not talking. Please explain what you mean by that and how you came to that conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was the "./configure" settings of your Apache and PHP?

PHP should have included at least --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs (change the path to your compiled Apache).

Sample:

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs --with-mysql=/usr/local/lib/mysql --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib --with-zlib
```

Comment: This is for Apache2: ./configure \ --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 \ --enable-so \ --enable-alias \ --enable-rewrite \ --enable-cache \ --enable-mem_cache \ --enable-headers \ --enable-expires \ --enable-auth-digest=shared \ --with-included-apr This is for PHP5: ./configure \ --prefix=/usr/local/php \ --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs \ --with-curl \ --enable-pdo \ --with-pdo_mysql \ --with-mysql \ --with-mysqli \ --with-mssql \ --with-libdir=lib64 \ --with-openssl \ --enable-soap \ --enable-xml \ --enable-xmlreader \ --enable-xmlwriter \ --enable-ftp \ --enable-calendar

Comment: continuing with php... --enable-cli \
--with-pear \
--with-gd \
--enable-mbstring \
--with-mcrypt

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood. When you start Apache by hand, does this work? You only need the service added?

Comment: I knew the apache was running because I started it using the apachectl command and ran the localhost page to make sure I was getting apache site. I say apache and php are not talking to one another because the simple phpinfo code and other echo commands show nothing but blank pages when i point to those .php files. Thank you

Comment: can you put your apache config in a gist or pastebin and update your question with it? What do you see in the access_log and error_log when you acces a phpinfo only page?

Comment: I managed to setup apachectl to start by adding in init.d. It's just that PHP isn't working on the browser. I installed PHP and made sure suitable changes were made within httpd.conf such as loadmodule commands, and they are all there, but I still get nothing but blank pages for php files

Comment: to investigate further I would need to have your apache config and your php script and it is most probably one of the two that is wrong

Comment: apache config meaning httpd.conf right? what file is php script? the script to ./configure?

Comment: in error_log i see "generating secret for digest authentication..." 
"caught SIGTERM, shutting down" 
"Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) PHP/5.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations" and nothing in access_log

Comment: by php script I mean your .php you're trying to access. Something like phpinfo.php if you try to access http://localhost/phpinfo.php. Based on your log, everything should work!

Comment: I'd like to send you the httpd.conf file, how do i gist or pastebin? or email? thanks! and yea it's a simple index.php placed under /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: https://gist.github.com/

Comment: git clone git://gist.github.com/1642518.git gist-1642518   is this right?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this...

Comment: try to add text outside of the <? ?> tags in your php file to see if it is served at all

Comment: chmod 755 -R htdocs fixed it! Thanks guys and jpiboily especially :O

Comment: You could have done chmod +x too